# Javascript createElement() not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Javascript `createElement()` is not working in Chrome but it works in IE and Firefox fine. Why?

Comment: @david, that should have been an answer, not a comment ;-)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, whatever it is. This is a "close: not a real question" problem not a "this is the solution" problem.

Answer (score 9):

It's working perfectly, use this code:

```
var catDiv = document.createElement("div");
catDiv.innerHTML = "Test";
document.body.appendChild(catDiv);
```

Another working example (if you have an element with Id = myTableBody in your HTML)

```
var appendingTo = document.getElementById("myTableBody");
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
tr.setAttribute("name", "i");
appendingTo.appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: I have used like document.createElement("<tr name=row"+i+">"); I got the error as Uncaught Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5

Comment: @Rekha: Because you have to write `t = document.createElement('tr');` and set the attribute later. Second: table rows have no `name` attribute anyway. You should add your code to your question so that people can *really* help you.

Answer (score 6):

```
var name = document.createElement("Div" );
```

will work. And later you can add the attributes like

```
name.colSpan="2";
document.body.appendChild(name);
```

Note: don't try to use angular brackets like `createElement("<div />")`.
It will not work in Chrome.

Edit: syntax issue in above code fixed. there should be a dot instead of comma.

Answer (score 2):

Beacause your code is messed up, there's nothing wrong with "createElement":

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <title></title>

        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
                    var div = document.createElement ("div");
                        div.style.border = "1px solid black";
                        div.style.margin = "20px";
                        div.style.padding = "10px";

                    document.body.appendChild (div);
                }
            }
        </script>

        <style></style>
    </head>

    <body></body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I also couldn't get `createElement()` to work in chrome. After reading **Caio's** post and testing the code provided I figured out what I was doing wrong.

On w3schools.com the examples they provide always use the **tag name** in all caps ex. `createElement("DIV")`, which is the way I was using it and with poor results.

After changing from **`"DIV"`** to **`"div"`** in my own code it instantly worked.

Thanks Caio.