# div - createElement is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create the `div` tag using javascript.? But why it is not working?
I have seen the [document.createElement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202699/document-createelement-not-working)

[Javascript createElement() not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861864/javascript-createelement-not-working-in-chrome)
But these answers are not suited for my script.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var div = '<div id = con style="width:auto; height:200px; Background:#2a2a2a">';
var x = document.createElement(div);
var y = document.getElementById('con');
y.innerHTML = "hello world";
document.body.appendChild(x);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You forget to wrap your `div` in quotes: `createElement('div')`

Comment: should be: `var div = '<div id = "con" style="width:auto; height:200px; Background:#2a2a2a">'` You just forget to quote to id.

Comment: @antyrat I'm call the `var div = `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert entire HTML structure all at once, you can use very useful, cross-browser and unfairly little known [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) method:

```
var div = '<div id="con" style="width:auto; height:200px; Background:#2a2a2a"></div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', div);
var y = document.getElementById('con');
y.innerHTML = "hello world";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Inside the <body> which is perfectly run. But i need to put inside the <head>. Im try it which is not working

Comment: When you put this code in `head`, by the time it's executed there is no `<body>` tag yet. So in order it to work in head you need to wrap it in for example in `window.onload` event: `window.onload = function() { /* code in answer*/ }`.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work like so. `.createElement()` only excepts the *type* of element you want to create, no predefined HTML snippet. So you have to create a *Div* Element using `document.createElement('div');` and work on that element afterwards. Like

For Instance

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'con';
    div.style.cssText = "width:auto; height:200px; Background:#2a2a2a";

document.body.appendChild( div );
```

If you don't need a reference to an *Element* and you only want to insert new HTML code, you can also use [`Element.prototype.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) like so

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', '<div id="con" style="width:auto; height:200px; Background:#2a2a2a">');
```

A further problem of your code here is that you try to access the DOM too early. Even if the code *would* work in its current form, you cannot access `document.body` in your `<head>` section because it wasn't fully initialized at that point. Either move the entire `<script>` source into the `<body>` section or attach a listener to [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) Event.

Comment: This is the correct answer. With plain JS, you need to define the attributes manually after creating the element with the tag name. If you want to create elements from HTML snippets, use jQuery or something like that.

Comment: @user3384402 Well it should, what is the problem over there ?

Comment: @jAndy I use your code and extra added  `var he = document.getElementById('con');
    he.innerHTML = ("Hello world");` then i run it not give the result.

Comment: @user3384402 I updated the answer. There are some more problematic things in your code you need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a predefined html like that, also since you are appending to body, the script should be inside the body element not in head

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var x = document.createElement('div');
            x.id = 'con';
            x.style.width = 'auto';
            x.style.height = '200px';
            x.style.background = '#2a2a2a';
            x.innerHTML = "hello world";
            document.body.appendChild(x);
            //no need to access `y` by id, use the reference returned by createElement to set the content
            //var y = document.getElementById('con');
            //y.innerHTML = "hello world";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```